# prefix multiple column names in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I wrote the following scala code :

```
 val someDF = Seq(
 |   (8, "bat"),
 |   (64, "mouse"),
 |   (-27, "horse")
 | ).toDF("number", "word")
```

My aim is to change the names of columns to "pap_number" ans "pap_word"

I wrote this:

```
val list = someDF.columns
```

and then

```
val result = list.foldLeft(df){(acc, names ) =>
 |   acc.withColumnRenamed(names, "pap_".concat(names)
 | }
```

But this doesn't work any idea about this

Comment: Notice you are changing the list "someDF.columns" you get, you did not change the DF itself.
You need to rename your columns in your DF.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? I replaced `df` by `someDF` and closed the missing parenthesis and it works like a charm on my side. Note that  in general, it is very helpful to post the error trace so that people can more easily see what's wrong.

Comment: yes right  this was because df instead of someDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one parenthesis and provided the wrong df.

```
scala> someDF.columns.foldLeft(someDF){ (acc, names) =>
 | acc.withColumnRenamed(names, "pap_".concat(names))
 | }
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [pap_number: int, pap_word: string]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use this library which extends spark functions: 
https://github.com/helkaroui/spark-tools

```
import org.charik.sparktools.sql.functions._
val renamedAllColumns = df.withColumnsPrefixed("prefix_")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
***Pyspark users can do the following***

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

prefix = 'click_'
df4 = df3.select([col(c).alias(prefix+c) for c in df3.columns])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 